# ERROR TypeError: this.test is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular.

I have to assign method to my paginator.getRangeLabel (I use standard label or suffixed depending on some conditions):

```
  this.paginator._intl.getRangeLabel = this.getLabel;
```

This is simplified code that works (but the logic in both method is copy pasted, it is quite long, here I reduced it):

```
 private getLabel(page: number, pageSize: number, length: number): string {
        return 'some string result'
    }

    private getLabelWithSuffix(page: number, pageSize: number, length: number): string {
        return 'some string result ...'
    }
```

I want to refactor this code to contain common method ad reduce copy paste.
And below are methods implementation.

```
private getLabel(page: number, pageSize: number, length: number): string {
        return this.test(page, pageSize, length, false);
    }

    private getLabelWithSuffix(page: number, pageSize: number, length: number): string {
        return this.test(page, pageSize, length, true);
    }

    private test(page: number, pageSize: number, length: number, suffix: boolean): string {
        return 'some string result' + (suffix ? '...' : '');
    }
```

This throws exception in console:

> ERROR TypeError: this.test is not a function
> at MatPaginatorIntl.getLabel [as getRangeLabel] (xxx.ts:21:21)
> at MatPaginator_Template (paginator.mjs:329:1469)
> at executeTemplate (core.mjs:9622:1)
> at refreshView (core.mjs:9488:1)
> at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10659:1)
> at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9284:1)
> at refreshView (core.mjs:9538:1)
> at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10659:1)
> at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9284:1)

Comment: I presume it's because in your case "this" refer to your class "Paginator", because you give it the method. " and not the component or service.
If you do directly in your component in `ngOnInit() {console.log(this.getLabel(1,1,1)}`
It Will work fine.
If you still want to do in this way your class has to look something like that.
`  paginator = {
 
    _intl : {
      getRangeLabel: this.getLabel,
      test : this.test,
    }
    
  };`

Comment: ah ofcourse it was about this. :) Thanks

Comment: The awnser given by Antoniossss seems good too, but you loose the key word "this" of your object/class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What this refers to is defined by how the function is called](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp). In your case `getLabel` is passed as a function without context and when it's called `this` will refer to the functional scope of where it is executed.
To pass a function with the bonded context you can just bind `this`:

```js
this.paginator._intl.getRangeLabel = this.getLabel.bind(this);
```

An alternative approach would be moving methods outside of the class as global functions then you will not need to bind the context.

Comment: I moved my function to global level

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 this.paginator._intl.getRangeLabel = this.getLabel.bind(this);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. I used Nico hint, I removed `this` from my code and created global `function test(length: number, pageSize: number, page: number, suffix: boolean)` and it works, I didn't check this binding.

Answer (score -1):

The error message "TypeError: this.test is not a function" typically occurs when you are trying to call a method or function that does not exist on the object (this) where it's being used. This error is commonly encountered in JavaScript and TypeScript.

To resolve this error, you need to ensure that the method or function is defined on the object you are trying to call it from. Here are a few common scenarios that can cause this error:

**Method Not Defined:**

```
var obj = { prop: 42,}; // 'test' function is not defined
obj.test(); // ERROR: TypeError: obj.test is not a function
```

**Solution:**
Make sure that the test function is defined within the object obj.

```
var obj = {
  prop: 42,
  test: function() {
    console.log("This is a test function.");
  }
};

obj.test(); // Correct, will call the 'test' function.
```

Please review your code and identify the specific scenario that is causing the error. If you provide more context or the code snippet where the error occurs, I can assist you in finding the solution.